# How to return JSON object in resolveException method of HandlerExceptionResolver in Spring MVC?

Tags: json, validation, spring-mvc, file-upload, max-size

While implementing a File Uploader controller in Spring MVC I stucked with one problem. My code snap is given below.

```
@Controller
public class FileUploader extends AbstractBaseController implements HandlerExceptionResolver
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
    {
        JSONObject returnObj = new JSONObject();
        if (file.isEmpty())
        {
            returnObj.put("success", "false");
            returnObj.put("message", "File is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //my file upload logic goes here 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                returnObj.put("success", "false");
                returnObj.put("message", "File not uploaded.");
            }
        }

        return returnObj;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object obj, Exception exception)
    {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        Map map = new HashMap();
        if (exception instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException)
        {
            // I want to return JSONObject from here like given below.
            /**
             * { "message":"File size exceeded", "success":"false" }
             * */
            map.put("message", "File size exceeded");
            map.put("success", "false");
            model.addObject(map);
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

and my spring configuration look likes

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="300000"/>
    </bean>
```

now In my controller I want to return JSONObject instead of ModelAndView in resolveException method in my controller as given in code snap because I am developing some like REST method to upload file.

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you use the Spring 3.2 above, I recommend this way.

1. At first, declare the ControllerAdvice.

   > ```
   > @Controller
   > @ControllerAdvice
   > public class JAttachfileApi extends BaseApi
   > ```
2. And make the Exception Handler to response JSON Object as following.

   > ```
   >     @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
   >     public @ResponseBody Map<String,Object> handleMaxUploadSizeExceededException(
   >  MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex) 
   >     {
   >
   >         Map<String,Object> result = getResult();
   >
   >         JFileUploadJsonResponse errorResult = new JFileUploadJsonResponse();
   >         errorResult.setError("Maximum upload size of "+ex.getMaxUploadSize()+" bytes exceeded.");
   >         List<JFileUploadJsonResponse> resultData = new ArrayList<JFileUploadJsonResponse>();
   >         resultData.add(errorResult);
   >         result.put("files", resultData);
   >
   >       return result;
   >     }
   > ```

Comment: Hi..what is ControllerAdvice?

Comment: Worked like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

You simply can annotate the method resolveException as  @ExceptionHandler() and then you can have its signature like any other controller method. So placing @ResponseBody before the return type should work.

"Much like standard controller methods annotated with a @RequestMapping annotation, the method arguments and return values of @ExceptionHandler methods can be flexible. For example, the HttpServletRequest can be accessed in Servlet environments and the PortletRequest in Portlet environments. The return type can be a String, which is interpreted as a view name, a ModelAndView object, a ResponseEntity, or you can also add the @ResponseBody to have the method return value converted with message converters and written to the response stream."

Comment: Hi, @user3014091, Thanks for your quick reply, but I can't change signature of resolveException by annotating it @ExceptionHandler() as I am overriding it from HandlerExceptionResolver.

Comment: Mayve the context is not completely clear for me. But I think you can move your exception handling in a different method that is "free" from inheritance and use the @ExceptionHanler annotation, so you're free to use all the "modern" implementation of controllers.

Comment: Hi.. angelodelia Thanks but @ExceptionHanler come into picture when you are not handling your Exception, but spring already handled MaxUploadSizeExceededException. They are just printing stack trace of that. So @ExceptionHanler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class) will not call anytime. I already tried that.